# Proof verification in Hatcher Algebraic Topology, Proposition 3.25

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, solution-verification, orientation

First, this is the link of the book, for convenience: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf#page=244

**Proposition 3.25** If $M$ is connected, then $M$ is orietable iff $\tilde M$ has two components.

(Here $M$ is an $n$-manifold. The definition of $\tilde M$ is constructed above the statement.)

**Proof.** If $M$ is connected, $\tilde M$ has either one or two components since it is a two-sheeted covering space of $M$. If it has two components, they are each mapped homeomorphically to $M$ by the covering projection, so $M$ is orientable. Conversely, if $M$ is orientable, it has exactly two orientations since it is connected, and each of these orientations defines a component of $\tilde M$.

I think this proof is fulled of just claims. I took quite lot of time verifying each sentence. I almost understood all, but the only thing that I couldn't is in the last sentence that the two orientations of $M$ define the two components of $\tilde M$. That is, how do I have to show that $\tilde{M}$ is not connected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @reuns I think the cylinder is the two-sheeted orientable cover of the Mobius strip

Comment: How would you construct $\bar{M}$ when $M$ is say the Möbius strip ? I think you should cover $M$ by finitely many charts from $(-1,1)^n\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ and use them to create the charts for $\bar{M}$, once you chose an orientation at $0$ it extends uniquely to $(-1,1)^n$, then the question is if those orientation agree or not from one chart to the other, if they do you have by definition oriented $M$, otherwise you get a double cover of $M$ by an oriented manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the two global orientations and call them $+1$ and $-1$. This gives you a map $\tilde M \to \{+1, -1\}$ which is continuous and surjective. So $\tilde M$ is disconnected. Conversely, the inverse images of $+1$ and $-1$ are each homeomorphic to $M$ so those are connected.

To see why the map is continuous you use the definition of the topology to show that $\tilde M$ is orientable (in particular it is locally orientable). So every point has a neighbourhood with a compatible orientation. Meaning $+1$ points have only $+1$ points in a neighbourhood of them and vice versa.